# Choose the RLoad resistor for zener diode

Tags: resistors, diodes, voltage-regulator, zener, basic

I need to calculate the Rload resistor range for the operation in this case:
[image]

I know that many times to calculate the Rseries but now he is given,
how does my teacher expect me to calculate the RL?
all I know is that the max current in Dz is 5mA(50mW Max), so how to calculate the range of RL?

Comment: Sounds like homework question with no effort. If there is no load, the Zener dissipates too much and explodes. If there is a short circuit for a load, then Zener can't regulate to 10V. So there must be a range of loads where Zener does not explode and load gets regulated 10V. Please try.

Comment: I don't know where to start, what is the parameter IZK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *all I know is that the max current in Dz is 5mA(50mW Max), so how to
> calculate the range of RL?*

- The max current and maximum input supply voltage will give you the value of \$R_{SERIES}\$
- Then, consider the lowest input supply voltage
- And, remove the zener diode from your thoughts temporarily
- Imagine it wasn't there
- Ask yourself what value of \$R_L\$ produces 10 volts at the output
- Recognize that if \$R_L\$ were any lower than that value there would be less than 10 volts out
- That gives you the bottom range value for \$R_L\$

> *I calculate the RL when VIN is 20v, the value is 2Kohm*

However, there is an extra subtlety in this picture: -

[image]

That subtlety implies that for proper regulation of the zener diode the minimum current that flows through the zener is 1 mA. So, the total load of the zener knee current and \$R_L\$ must be such that their net loading is 2 kΩ.

2 kΩ (as part of an ideal potential divider) would produce 10 volts at the output but, if you calculate the contribution to that impedance by the zener at its knee current you find it's 10 volts ÷ 1 mA = 10 kΩ.

Hence, to calculate \$R_L\$ we have to do this: -

$$\dfrac{1}{R_L} = \dfrac{1}{2k} - \dfrac{1}{10 k} = \dfrac{1}{2.5k}$$

Hence, \$R_L\$ is 2.5 kΩ (when accounting for the Zener's knee current).

Comment: I calculate the RL when VIN is 20v, the value is 2Kohm, but the answer for this question is 2.5kohm<RL<5kohm ...

Comment: @Knowledge I've amended my answer to take into account the Zener diode knee current.

Comment: What about the upper limit? why the max RL is 5kohm? if I take vin=24v and use Izk=1mA its still not 5kohm

Comment: That's as easy to work out as it is to upvote my answer.